# Function Called Multiple Times

Tags: java, function

Trying to code a text game and when asking for GameSettings class input, the function gets called 3 times. I am trying to send the code back and forth between the classes, the reason why I am using different classes to make the code a bit more clean so that when I am sending the monsterHealth...etc it is readable.

Game.Java

```
package src;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Game {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 

    GameSettings GameSettings = new GameSettings();
    GameSettings.init();


//  GameSettings.Classes();

    GameSettings.StartLogic();

    if (src.GameSettings.Classes().equals("mage")) {
        System.out.println("mage"); 
    }
    else if (src.GameSettings.Classes().equals("warrior")) {
        System.out.println("warrior");  
    }
    else if (src.GameSettings.Classes().equals("archer")) {
        System.out.println("archer");   
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Non valid");

    }
}
}
```

GameSettings.Java

```
package src;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class GameSettings extends Game {

public interface classChoice {

}
public int playerHp;
private static Scanner scanner;
private static String nameInput;
private static String classChoice;

private String mage;
private String archer;
private String warrior;

public void init() {
scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome To Fizzle's Text Based RPG\nWhat Is Your 
    Name?");
    nameInput = scanner.nextLine(); 
}
    public static String Classes() {
    System.out.println("Welcome " + nameInput + " What Class Would You Like 
    To Be?\n(mage)\n(warrior)\n(archer)");
    classChoice = scanner.nextLine();

    return classChoice;

}

public void StartLogic() {
    playerHp = 10;
    System.out.println(classChoice);    


}


 }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "the function"? How does this even compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your problem. In the

```
 GameSettings.StartLogic();

    if (src.GameSettings.Classes().equals("mage")) {
        System.out.println("mage"); 
    }
    else if (src.GameSettings.Classes().equals("warrior")) {
        System.out.println("warrior");  
    }
    else if (src.GameSettings.Classes().equals("archer")) {
        System.out.println("archer");   
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Non valid");

    }
```

You're calling the GameSettings.Classes().equals() method three times. Instead of doing this, define a `String` variable before the if/else block like this:

```
 GameSettings.StartLogic();

    String input = src.GameSettings.Classes();

    if (input.equals("mage")) {
        System.out.println("mage"); 
    }
    else if (input.equals("warrior")) {
        System.out.println("warrior");  
    }
    else if (input.equals("archer")) {
        System.out.println("archer");   
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Non valid");

    }
```

This is because when you use the if/else statement, you shouldn't call methods that rely on luck or user input inside of the statement, but define them as variables beforehand and pass those in as arguments to the if/else statement. Hope this helps!

Comment: if he wanted to improve his code, he could put the String literal as variable on which the equals is called. If he wants to improve readability, he could use a switch instead of if else if else if else

Answer (score 0):

Hello Fizzle! :)

Please clarify your question. 
I added a few comments to your code:

**Game.java**

```java
import java.io.IOException;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        GameSettings GameSettings = new GameSettings();
        GameSettings.init();

        GameSettings.StartLogic(); //returns null

        if (GameSettings.Classes().equals("mage")) {
            System.out.println("mage");
        } else if (GameSettings.Classes().equals("warrior")) {
            System.out.println("warrior");
        } else if (GameSettings.Classes().equals("archer")) {
            System.out.println("archer");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Non valid");

        }

    }
}
```

**GameSettings.java**

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GameSettings extends Game {

    //why did you declare an Interface?
    public interface classChoice {

    }

    public int playerHp;
    private static Scanner scanner;
    private static String nameInput;
    private static String classChoice;

    public void init() {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome To Fizzles Text Based RPG What Is Your Name?");
        nameInput = scanner.nextLine();
    }

    public static String Classes() {
        System.out.println("Welcome " + nameInput + " What Class Would You Like To Be?\n(mage)\n(warrior)\n(archer)");
        classChoice = scanner.nextLine();

        return classChoice;

    }

    //why are you calling this method beforehand?
    public void StartLogic() {
        playerHp = 10;
        System.out.println("Your Class:" + classChoice);

    }

}
```